# How to pass text box values to next page using Hyper link in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I Want to pass my text box values in the jsp  through hyperlink .both the text box and Hyperlink are in the same jsp page.How can i achieve this

Comment: just google it before asking...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

use `<a>` tag & using `QueryString` pass the value of textbox to other `JSP` page.

```
<a href="pass.jsp" onclick="addTextBoxData(this)">

<script>
function addTextBoxData(e){
    e.href = e.href + "?textbox=" + document.getElementById('textboxID').value;
}
</script>
```

you just need to pass reference of tag using `this`.

then it ll append data `?textbox=textbox value`

so it ll be `/pass.jsp?textbox=txt`

Comment: This depends on javascript working / being enabled. @dovy's answer is more adequate

Comment: @DavidBrossard : Yes it is. I am agree with you but most of browsers are Javascript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You use `GET` method, for example, Create file `index.jsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="index.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="txtUserName">Username: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName"/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="emailUser">Email: </label></td>
            <td><input type="email" id="emailUser" name="emailUser"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Go to: `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp` (I use default port 8080 with Tomcat)
When enter
username: `myname`
email: `myname@example.com`
and press `Submit` button. See browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.jsp?txtUserName=myname&emailUser=myname%40example.com
```

[image]